# CSS - position relative/absolute to a text inline element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a navbar menu with dropdown tabs. The text are populated dynamically. I need to get the caret icons positioned next to the text at any given viewport size. Here is what I'm referring too (see green carets)

[image]

Below is the code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}
.filler-left {
  // margin-right: auto;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: brown;
}
.filler-right {
  background-color: black;
  width: 600px;
}
.menu-wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.menu-btn {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.text {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.caret {
  min-width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="filler-left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <span class="text">lo netrunner</span>
      <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
    </div>
     <div class="menu-btn">
       <span class="text">Planes of Salads & Greatness</span>
      <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
    </div>
     <div class="menu-btn">
       <span class="text">Formulas & Computations</span>
      <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filler-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen reference as well if this makes it an easier to debug, but it's same as code snippet above:
https://codepen.io/vincentntang/pen/f44a23aa2b2de633e3d2dffa1e83c0b9

The text's width is not based on any padding but rather the length of the first word on the 2nd line as part of a HTML text standards

Things I've tried:

- I tried using a `position: relative` on the inline text and a `position:absolute` for the caret image against it, but this didn't work out
- I've tried using `width: fit-content` against the `text` class element, but puts the text of "Planes of Salads & Greatness" at 3 lines instead of 2 for all viewport sizes. At larger viewports I'd like just a single line

Answer (score 1):

You can

- apply `display: inline-block;`and side padding to `.text` to create space for `.caret`
- apply `position: relative;` to the `.menu-btn`, to make it the position reference for the `.caret` element,
- apply `position: absolute` to `.caret`, add a `right` setting for the distance to the right border and a `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)` to position it properly

Change the `right`, `padding`and - if needed) `margin` settings as needed...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}
.filler-left {
  // margin-right: auto;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: brown;
}
.filler-right {
  background-color: black;
  width: 600px;
}
.menu-wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.menu-btn {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  
}
.text {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.caret {
  min-width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="filler-left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <span class="text">lo netrunner</span>
      <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
    </div>
     <div class="menu-btn">
       <span class="text">Planes of Salads & Greatness</span>
      <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
    </div>
     <div class="menu-btn">
       <span class="text">Formulas & Computations</span>
      <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filler-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `caret` images inside their relevant `span` elements and give the `span` elements the same flex properties as the parent above.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}
.filler-left {
  // margin-right: auto;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: brown;
}
.filler-right {
  background-color: black;
  width: 600px;
}
.menu-wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.menu-btn {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.text {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inherit;
  align-items: inherit;
}

.caret {
  min-width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="filler-left">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <span class="text">
        lo netrunner
        <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
      </span>
    </div>
     <div class="menu-btn">
       <span class="text">
         Planes of Salads & Greatness
         <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
       </span>
    </div>
     <div class="menu-btn">
       <span class="text">
         Formulas & Computations 
         <img class="caret" src="https://assets.codepen.io/867725/Icon_Caret.svg" />
       </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filler-right">
  </div>
</div>
```